# Error with copy() function in reading excel files using python

Tags: python, excel, automation

I am working on a python prtogram that reads an excel file and based on the information in that file, writes data in the same file

This is my code:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlutils import copy

location = "C:\\Users\\adarsh\\Desktop\\Python\\Other\\Blah.xls"
readbook = xlrd.open_workbook(location)
workbook = xlutils.copy(readbook)
sheet = workbook.get_sheet(0)
```

I get this error when I run my code:

```
workbook = xlutils.copy(readbook)
AttributeError: module 'xlutils' has no attribute 'copy'
```

There is an error saying that there is no attribute `copy` even though online tutorials use that feature
I don't know how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you haven't imported the right function from the right place. Try this:

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
```

Then you can simply call:

```
copy(readbook)
```

Answer (score 0):

You imported copy specifically from the module so you shouldn't need the xlutils.copy() it should just be copy()